# Deleting a character midstring (iterable) in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long list of strings which contain 4 pieces of information.  I am indexing them by splitting them at whitespace.  Unfortunately, in a few of the strings, there is a whitespace also within the second piece of information.  I would like to be able to delete any whitespace which occurs between two colons.  Here a few items from the list to demonstrate:

> abroad a:at:n request 1
>
> abroad a:at:n silence 1
>
> abroad a:at:n time 6
>
> abroad a:because of:n schedule 1
>
> abroad a:by:n american 1
>
> abroad a:by:n bank 1
>
> abroad a:by:n blow 1

So, my problem arises in the 4th line above.  Obviously I could manually delete the space to solve the problem, but the list is thousands of lines.  Also, I could write code that replaced any occurrences of "because of" with "becauseof", but that is not the only two word sequence that occurs.  In addition, the third slice sometimes contains "because of" and I want to preserve the whitespace there.  My current code, which is attempting to return the frequency of each sequence, looks like this:

```
import sys
import pprint

occ_list = []
observed = {}

lines = sys.stdin.readlines()

for line in lines:
    l = line.strip()
    i = l.split(' ')
    word = i[0]
    rel = i[1]
    wirts = i[2:-1]
    wirt = ' '.join(wirts)  # Word-in-relation-to (which may be compund)
    occ = i[-1]             # Frequency of specific "word, rel, wirt"
    arb = (word, rel, wirt)
    occ_list.append(int(occ))

    if not arb in observed.keys():
            observed[arb] = []
    if not occ in observed[arb]:
            observed[arb].append(int(occ)/float(1064542))

pprint.pprint(observed)
```

This works except for the aforementioned lines with the extra whitespace.

I would appreciate any advice.  (I am using python 3.2)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Start by splitting at the whitespace. If the second item *doesn't* contain whitespace then there should be 2 colons in it; if there's only one colon then there *was* whitespace in the second item, so the second and third items are part of a single item.

```
parts = line.split()
if parts[1].count(":") == 1:
    parts[1 : 3] = [" ".join(parts[1 : 3])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect there to be any colons in your text file besides those in the second bit of information? If not I'd recommend splitting on the colons to remove the spaces. If however you want to allow for other colons in other pieces of information, then I'd suggest using the [`re` (regex)](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module.

```
# Split on colons:
bits = l.split(':')
# remove spaces in the second part
bits[1] = bits[1].replace(' ','')
# join again
l = ':'.join(bits)
# do rest of code.
```

Also, you alluded to this in your question I think, but I want to clarify. Do you get lines like this?

```
abroad a:by:because of american 1
```

And in that case, do you want `rel` to be `a:by:because of`?

And can information part 3 (`wirts`) be multiple words? What about:

```
abroad a:by:because of american silence 2
```

How would you work out which words belonged to which?

I think you'd need to have a dictionary of words with spaces that are permitted in the `a:by:xxxx` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
import re
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

occ_list = []
observed = defaultdict(list)
for line in fileinput.input():
    m = re.search(r"(\S+)\s+([^:]+:[^:]+:\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d+)", line)
    if m:
       word, rel, wirt, occ = m.groups()
       occ = int(occ)
       occ_list.append(occ)
       observed[word, rel, wirt].append(occ / 1064542.0)

pprint(occ_list)
pprint(dict(observed))
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/ukWDF)

```
[1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1]
{('abroad', 'a:at:n', 'request'): [9.393711098293914e-07],
 ('abroad', 'a:at:n', 'silence'): [9.393711098293914e-07],
 ('abroad', 'a:at:n', 'time'): [5.636226658976349e-06],
 ('abroad', 'a:because of:n', 'schedule'): [9.393711098293914e-07],
 ('abroad', 'a:by:n', 'american'): [9.393711098293914e-07],
 ('abroad', 'a:by:n', 'bank'): [9.393711098293914e-07],
 ('abroad', 'a:by:n', 'blow'): [9.393711098293914e-07]}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is pretty much what I was looking for.  I had tried to use re earlier, but given up; I was implementing it incorrectly I guess.  I'm using the following instead because it's a little clearer to me and also captures multi-word phrases in the "wirt" part:       m = re.search(r"(\S+)\s(\S:\w+\s*\S*:\S+)\s(\S+\s*\S*\s*\S*)\s(\d+)", line)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version using just `split` and `rsplit`:

```
for line in lines:
    word, s = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
    s, occ = s.rsplit(' ', 1)
    rel, s = s.rsplit(':', 1)
    s, wirt = s.split(' ', 1)       
    arb = (word, rel + ':' + s, wirt)
    occ_list.append(int(occ))
```